# Talend - Transfer multiple tables between two servers without dynamic schema

Tags: mysql, etl, talend

I have to create a job that transfers multiple tables across servers incrementally or entire table. But I cant get to do it despite trying various component combinations. Please suggest solution other than dynamic schema. I know it can be done with context variables but can't figure out the procedure or steps.
P.S. I'm new to Talend and just experimenting with the components, kindly let me know if there is a solution with context variables or tDBoutputBulk or DbtableList components.

Comment: dynamic schema are only available in paid version of Talend , could you specify what version you are using and specify also the (input and output of what you are trying to reach)

Comment: Show us for example un table with some data and where do you migrate it

Comment: @AmineBenKhelifa I'm working on Talend Open Studio, and I have to move tables from one server to the other.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same way to copy the tables within one database, the SELECT INTO but use a fully qualified tables names database.schema.object_name instead like so ,

You can use a 2 `tDBRow` components  with using  :

- The first one to  :

  ```
  USE TheOtherDB;
  ```
- The second one to :

  ```
  SELECT *
  INTO NewTable
  FROM TheFirstDB.Schemaname.OldTable
  ```

This will create a new table `Newtable`  in the database `TheOtherDB`  from the table `OldTable`  whih belongs to the `databaseTheFirstDB`

Comment: I dint get it, how can I transfer multiple tables through this? This job would still move one table at a time. Can this be achieved using table list component?

Comment: add a tDbtableList  before the tDBRow  and instead of OldTable put "+row.OldTable+" coming from your tDbtableList

Comment: It doesn't work, is there any work around using a file to determine table names and then outputting the data tables on destination schema? I have been going round and round in circles but unable to find a solution to the issue.

Comment: you have to show us what you tried so that we can help